# Is it possible to express $\sum_{k \geq 0} a_k a_{k+1} x^k$ in terms of $A(x) = \sum_{k \geq 0} a_k x^k$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I originally tried some variations on $A(x)^2 = (\sum_{k \geq 0} a_k x^k)^2$, but this only gets me to $A(x)^2 = (\sum_{k \geq 0} a_k x^k)^2 = \sum_{k \geq 0} (\sum_{0 \leq i \leq k}a_ia_{k-i})x^k$, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Is there any way to express this in the form of $A(x)$ or is this not possible?

Comment: If we take $a_k = 1/k!$ then $A(x) = e^x$ while $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k a_{k+1} x^k$ is [apparently](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+of+%28x%5Ek%2Fk%21+*+%281%2F%28k%2B1%29%21%29%29+from+k+%3D+1+to+infinity) a Bessel function. So, if there is a solution, it's at least going to result in some special functions and won't be a simple closed-form answer.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the question is too vague to resolve. When you say express $\sum a_ka_{k+1}x^k$ in terms of $\sum a_kx^k$, do you want a power series $f(x)$ such that $f(\sum a_kx^k)=\sum a_ka_{k+1}x^k$? This will not work. Any such power series would obey $f(c\sum a_kx^k)=c^2f(\sum a_kx^k)$ implying $f=ax^2$, but this also doesn't work. Did you mean something else?

*At first I misread, and thought that you wanted to express $\sum a_kx^k$ in terms of $\sum a_ka_{k+1}x^k$. This is not possible as the following example shows.

Consider $a_k=1$ when $k$ is even and $0$ otherwise vs $b_k=0$ when $k$ is even and $1$ otherwise.

$$\sum a_ka_{k+1}x^k=\sum b_kb_{k+1}x^k=0$$

but

$$\sum a_kx^k\ne\sum b_kx^k$$

*It has now been clarified that you are asking whether there is a *function* from power series to power series which maps $\sum a_kx^k$ to $\sum a_ka_{k+1}x^k$. In this form, the answer is obvious: the rule $f(\sum a_kx^k)=\sum a_ka_{k+1}x^k$ manifestly defines such a function! So, yes, there is a function satisfying your requirements.

I suspect that this answer is somewhat unsatisfying, assuming that you wanted a 'nice formula' for the function, not just to restate what you asked as the function's definition. However, this rule is already enough to be a mathematical function. Any rule whatsoever which is unambiguously defined is a function.

Comment: I think I'm still confused. I can see that there can be 2 sequences $a_k$ and $b_k$ such that $A(x) = \sum a_kx^k \neq \sum b_kx^k = B(x)$. But it's not immediately clear to me why there couldn't exist a function $f(A(x))=\sum a_k a_{k+1}x^k = \sum b_k b_{k+1}x^k = f(B(x))$.

Comment: I misread the question, this only shows that you can't express $\sum a_kx^k$ in terms of $\sum a_ka_{k+1}x^k$

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault: to clarify, $f$ would be a function mapping a power series to another power series. For example, for $f_1(A(x)) = x \frac{d}{dx} A(x) = \sum_{k \geq 0} k a_k x^k$ we have $f_1$ mapping $A(x)$ to $x \frac{d}{dx}A(x)$. For $f_2(A(x)) = A(x)^2 = \sum_{k \geq 0} (\sum_{0 \leq i \leq k}a_ia_{k-i})x^k$, $f_2$ maps $A(x)$ to $A(x)^2$. I was hoping there would be a (relatively simple) $f$ such that $ f(A(x)) = \sum a_k a_{k+1} x^k$.